# Python interactive menu in terminal/putty etc

Tags: python, python-3.x, micropython, adafruit-circuitpython

I was wondering if there's a way to create an interactive menu (table in this case) within the terminal window?

A crude example would be something similar to this:

```
   +++++1000+++2000+++3000+++4000++
   +  0|<val>| <val>| <val>| <val>+
   + 25|<val>| <val>| <val>| <val>+            
   + 50|<val>| <val>| <val>| <val>+
   + 75|<val>| <val>| <val>| <val>+
   +100|<val>| <val>| <val>| <val>+
   ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

- first row & col would be reference values;
- `<val>` would like to be a default value in the beginning (e.g. populated with 255) but this is the value that I'd like to change with a desired one.
- also this has to be done with Python's standard libraries (am trying to implement this with Micropython/Circuitpython).

Probably the best example I can give is this guy: [follow until 0:50 or so.](https://youtu.be/KXMqQKf_F3U?t=21)

For what I know he's done it with an Arduino/C++.

Comment: Yes, this is possible. Did you try it? What was the problem?

Comment: i believe i'm looking for a way/the way of making it possible... hopefully that answers both your questions...

Comment: Would python' curses' work? https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html#curses-howto because there's a micropyhton version, ucurses https://github.com/micropython/micropython-lib/tree/master/ucurses

Comment: I believe Circuitpython has the curses lib as well; would you know how to implement the above with curses?